# How to replace all textlink and add <a href> tag using php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i want to add `<a href="">` to all textlink which i missed add `<a href="">` when i submit post.

Ex:

```
<a href"http://google.com">google.com</a> and https://paypal.com
```

And i just want to add `<a href="">` for text `https://paypal.com` which i missed add `<a href="">`

Thanks!

Comment: `<a href"` you realize you're missing an `=` here.

Comment: Not at all, I just want to say easy to understand.
Full : <a href="">

Comment: So you want to parse plain text for URLs and link them, ignoring previous linked content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using `preg_replace` function and *negative lookbehind assertion*:

```
$str = '<a href="http://google.com">google.com</a> and https://paypal.com';
$result = preg_replace("/(?<![=\">])https?:\/\/([^\s]+)/", '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $str);

print_r($result);
```

The output(as source code):

```
<a href="http://google.com">google.com</a> and <a href="paypal.com">paypal.com</a>
```

`(?<!=\")` - negative lookbehind assertion, ensures that matched URL is not preceded by attribute assignment `="`

Comment: Just one more problem. I tried with this string:
`<a href="https://example.net/?goto=http://google.com" target="_blank">google.com</a> and https://paypal.com`

and output:
`http://google.org" target="_blank">google.org and https://paypal.com`

How can i fix it?

Comment: @RomanPerekrest Output has </a> at the end :(

`<a href="https://example.com/?goto=https://google.com" target="_blank"><a href="google.com</a>">google.com</a></a> and <a href="paypal.com">paypal.com</a>`

Comment: this `$str = '<a href="https://example.net/?goto=http://google.com" target="_blank">google.com</a> and https://paypal.com';
$result = preg_replace("/(?<![=\"])https?:\/\/([^\s]+)/", '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $str);` gives me the output `<a href="https://example.net/?goto=http://google.com" target="_blank">google.com</a> and <a href="paypal.com">paypal.com</a>`

Comment: I followed your string then everything works fine. But at this point `<a href="https://example.net/?goto=http://google.com" target="_blank">http://google.com</a>` give me the output `google.com</a>`, just try my string you'll see! Thank you so much.